# Google application engine with python 3.7 standard environment and endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I would like to use Google Cloud Endpoints with GAE using the newly (summer 2018) released Python 3.7 standard environment.
However, no matter what I try, I cannot seem to get http requests to go through the Endpoints service. They seem to get routed straight to the GAE code, without e.g. any authentication (API key checking) being performed. When I use GAE flex environment it works fine however.

Any suggestions what to try/check? When I look on Google Cloud Console under Google Endpoints, I see the deployments of the service for the correct app domain (with version 0.0.1). I also see the methods listed as per my openapi YAML file. However, I do not see any requests show up in the tracking chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python 3.7 environment does not yet have support for Google Cloud Endpoints, unfortunately. I would recommend you stick with the flex environment for the time being.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize it didn't work because it simply wasn't (yet) supported but diving deeper into the documentation indeed confirms this. I was excited about Google adding support for Python3.7 but it looks like I still may have no choice but to stick to the flex environment until some point later in the future.

Comment: Mainly replying to get notifications on this subject. I'll add that the documentation as it is now is very misleading on the subject of authentication.

Comment: Yes, actually! Please see https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-cloud-endpoints/MnbLC95W1y4/nbmrUkVWBgAJ for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine Standard environment currently support Java 7, Java 8, Python 2.7, Go, PHP and Node.js languages.

If you want to use Python 3.7 then you must use the Google App Engine Flexible environment. However, it supports Python 3.7 beta version in its second generation as of now ([for more details](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/appengine-generation)).

For more details [refer to this document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/)

Comment: Yes, Google App Engine Standard (beta) works fine for me with Python 3.7.
(that was not the problem I was facing however).